# I would like to exit a program if no input is read from user (blank line)

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am writing a program that stores the numbers entered by a user but exits if a blank is entered.

I have tried making it a char array and checking the length. If the length is bigger than 0, then it means there is and input so it will store the input. If the length is 0 it means there is no input and therefore exiting the loop.

```
do 
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer ('blank' to exit): ");
            String sInput=reader.next();
            char[] cArrInput=sInput.toCharArray();
            int iInput=cArrInput[0];
            if (cArrInput.length>0)
            {
                numbers[count]=iInput;  
                count=count+1;
            }
            else if (sInput.length()==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }while(count<100);
```

I am expecting it to break when there is no input from the user but instead the blank line is just visual and the code still stores the next number entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem :** You are using **next()** method of Scanner class, which wait for user next input.

**Solution :**

Use **nextLine()**  method.

**Use Following :**

```
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numbers[] = new int[100];
        int count=0;
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer ('blank' to exit): ");
            String sInput=reader.nextLine();
            char[] cArrInput=sInput.toCharArray();
            if (cArrInput.length>0)
            {
                numbers[count]=cArrInput[0];
                count=count+1;
            }
            else if (sInput.length()==0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }while(count<100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `nextLine` instead and pressing `<enter>`.

This is a simplified version

```
do
{
      System.out.print("Enter an integer ('blank' to exit): ");
      String sInput=reader.nextLine();

      if (sInput.length()>0)
      {
          count=count+1;
      }
      else 
      {
          break;
      }
}while(count<100);
```